# Changing the Resource Location of an existing Eclipse project

Tags: eclipse

I have wanted to do this a few times, for various reasons.

Firstly in the case where I have specified the Location incorrectly when I created the project. This project is part of a larger project, and I either want to go up or down a directory level to include more or less other stuff.

Secondly in the case where I have an existing eclipse project. I want to reuse the project on a different source tree (actually a different subversion branch of the same project).

The Resource Location field seems to be read only. The only way of achieving the above that I've found is creating a new project. Does anyone have any way of doing this?

Edit: I only want to change the Resource Location, not move the whole project.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not possible!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The location of a project is the location of its `.project` file. So you need to delete project (Do NOT select delete content checkbox), then move the `.project` file to a new location and import the project from there.

Creating new project does pretty much the same except you do not loose any project specifics/types.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. You can do that by using the following option:

On the Project, Right click and select option "Refactor" and then choose the option "Move".
This will pop up a dialog box. Specify the folder where you want your project to be.

Once the move operation is successful, your project is moved to a new location and you will see that Resource Location is pointing to a new folder that you have specified.

Comment: I only want to change the resource location, not move the whole project.